# Is scalar variable multiplication of $0/1$ variable array possible in $MILP$?

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

I remember somewhere seeing the following. If $x$ and $y$ are integer variables then we cannot multiply them easily unless we know a bound $B$ on them.

> Suppose I have an array $\overline x=[x_1\dots x_n]\in\{0,1\}^n$ and $0\leq y\leq B_y$ holds and entries of $x$ and variable $y$ are integers then is it possible to multiply $y\cdot \overline x$ with no extra integer variables and only $O(n\log B_y)$ real variables in $MILP$? I want real variables $z_1,\dots,z_n$ that the $MILP$ should have with the result $z_1=y\cdot x_1,\dots,z_n=y\cdot x_n$.

Comment: What does it mean here to 'multiply $y\cdot x$' here? Have this expression in a constraint? In the goal? As the result of the linear program? Please specify.

Comment: @DiscreteLizard Do you know what MILP is?

Comment: Yes, a mixed integer linear program. So, you want to use multiplication as a constraint on some real variables $z$. This is clearer, thanks.

Comment: @Discretelizard Both $y$ and $x_i$ are variables and that is the catch.